# How to include a dummy tr in a table just to set column widths with "table-layout" set to "fixed" but with height of zero

Tags: html, css

I want to programmatically inject column widths to set widths of the column. To do so, the table's table-layout CSS must be set to 'fixed' and the first row's column width is used throughout the table.

So I attempted the following:

```html
        <style>
          td { 
            border: 1px solid gray; 
          }
        </style>

        <table style="table-layout:fixed;border:1px solid black;" >
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="border:none;width:200px;"></td>
                <td style="border:none;width:300px;"></td>
                <td style="border:none;width:150px;"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Data Row 1, cell 1</td>
                <td>Data Row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>Data Row 1, cell 3</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <td>Footer Row 1, cell 1</td>
                <td>Footer Row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>Footer Row 1, cell 3</td>
              </tr>
           </tfoot>
        </table>
```

I have included tfoot just to ensure that it works with footer (and later with thead too!).

The problem is that it inserts a small space for the dummy 'tr'.
I tried setting display to 'none' which takes the effect of the dummy div all together.  I tried setting height to 0; line-height to 0. The dummy tr insists of sitting there with a small (1px?) height. How do I set its height to zero yet use the td widths?

Comment: you did not reset border-spacing nor border-collapse. Are looking for : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup no need then to create an empty row

Comment: @G-Cyr The /td part was a typo when copying/editing from the real page.  Corrected. I tried setting border-spacing. I do not want to set border-collapse because I want the original table to be left intact.

Comment: @G-Cyr  Perfect! colgroup did it. If you post it as an answer, will be a pleasure to accept it.

Comment: Just did and proposed the nth-child approach too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider [colgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup) or css selector [nth-child(n)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

> The HTML `<colgroup>` element defines a group of columns within a table.

or

> The `:nth-child()` CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their position in a group of siblings.

Examples below including your own code at first to let you see difference nd the 2 options *(colgroup or css )*

```css
tr {
  background: gray/* see us */
}

[class] td {
  width: 150px;
}

[class] td:first-child {/*selector similar to [class] td:nth-child(1){} */
  width: 200px;
}


[class] td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Your empty row</h1>
<table style="table-layout:fixed;border:1px solid black;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="border:none;width:200px;"></td>
      <td style="border:none;width:300px;"></td>
      <td style="border:none;width:150px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data Row 1, cell 1</td>
      <td>Data Row 1, cell 2</td>
      <td>Data Row 1, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Footer Row 1, cell 1</td>
      <td>Footer Row 1, cell 2</td>
      <td>Footer Row 1, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<hr>
<h1><code>colgroup</code> tag</h1>
<table style="table-layout:fixed;border:1px solid black;">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:200px;" /><!-- col  can be style from nth-child() selector too to keep html clean of inline style -->
    <col style="width:300px;" />
    <col style="width:150px;" />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data Row 1, cell 1</td>
      <td>Data Row 1, cell 2</td>
      <td>Data Row 1, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Footer Row 1, cell 1</td>
      <td>Footer Row 1, cell 2</td>
      <td>Footer Row 1, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<hr>
<h1>nth-child() approach</h1>
<table class style="table-layout:fixed;border:1px solid black;">
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Data Row 1, cell 1</td>
      <td>Data Row 1, cell 2</td>
      <td>Data Row 1, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Footer Row 1, cell 1</td>
      <td>Footer Row 1, cell 2</td>
      <td>Footer Row 1, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: I am using the colgroup approach because i think the nth-child approach will also need to handle th and is relatively more verbose. Am I correct? Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @asinix you are corect and you won't have problems with cell that might span through few columns ;) on the other side : `tr > :nth-child(x)` will select both td and th, it will only look for the position that matches